# Getting meaningful error messages from fstream's in C++

Tags: c++, exception, stl, portability, defensive-programming

What is the best way to get meaningful file access error messages, in a portable way from std::fstreams ? The primitiveness of `badbits` and `failbits` is getting to be bit annoying. I have written my own exception hierarchies against win32 and POSIX before, and that was far more flexible than the way the STL does it.

I am getting "basic::ios_clear" as an error message from the `what` method of a downcasted catch (`std::exception`) of a `fstream`  which has exceptions enabled. This doesn't mean much to me, although I do know what the problem is I'd like my program to be a tad more informative so that when I start deployment a few months later my life will be easier.

Is there anything in Boost to extract meaningful messages out of the `fstream`'s implementation cross platform and cross STL implementation ?

Comment: +1 for the question - I'm having this issue, too. Seems ridiculous to have such a basic interface that cannot provide a meaningful error message. At the very least the APR (Apache Portable Runtime) has provided this. It is extremely important to be able to communicate the Operating System's issue with a filename, such as "invalid permissions", or "disk error", etc to the user. Otherwise the program, correctly, stops functioning, but the user is left with no idea what actions to take to rectify the problem.

Answer (score 8):

Nobody stops you from also checking `errno`/`strerror` (e.g. in your exception handler) for a more specific reason for failure.

#### UPDATE -- regarding portability

Incidentally, IIRC Visual Studio's `fstream` implementation calls the `_open`/`_read`/`_write`/etc. CRT methods, which **set `errno`**.  **Microsoft makes no guarantee about `GetLastError` still containing the correct value** after the CRT methods return.  Idem for the cygwin, mingw etc. implementations, which set `errno` with no claims or guarantees about `GetLastError`.

So I stand by *my* claim that all you need, can, and therefore want to do is check `errno`.

Now, given all of the above, if you still want to complicate your life and overengineer by using `Boost::System` instead of simply calling `strerror` then I guess my definition and your definition of elegance and simplicity are not the same. :)

Comment: Just because "no body stops me" does not mean your suggestion is anywhere near elegent. Also I have said the following "I have written my own exception hierarchies against win32 and POSIX before" and finally I have mentioned portability as being a desirable feature as well. So this answer adds no value. Thanks though.

Comment: @Hassan Syed: The only thing in boost that comes close to this is `Boost::System` ( http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/system/doc/index.html ), and that's not going to help you with iostreams.

Comment: I don't want to sound finicky, but while " **RE** Writing " uniform error handling for OS abstractions is indeed the norm, this is the **EXACT** thing my question **is aiming to address**. Rehashing the obvious --which has also been addressed in the quesstion -- is not a solution. I don't want to re-invent the wheel, I am asking if there is a modern robus solution to my problem.

Comment: Thank you billy (+1), I have known of its existence, I guess I will give the library a closer look.

Comment: Billy upon closer inspection, boost::system is indeed the **exact solution** to my question. If you create the answer I can accept it :D. I was avoiding it due to it not having tutorial style documentation :D

Comment: @Hassan, I fail to see what is inelegant about the solution, how `errno`  is not portable (it is in fact your only portable choice), and what anyone other than you was supposed to make of your "I have written my own exception hierarchies". You can wrap and abstract it all you want, at the end of the day you *will* have to read `errno`.

Comment: Someone "WILL HAVE TO" read errno, that someone does not have to be me -- "All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection", I don't want to provide this level of indirection, yet again. I hope We can all agree that reuse is good in software engineering ?

Answer (score 1):

What information do you want? `badbit` indicates an I/O error. `eofbit` indicates eof. `failbit` indicates a parse error.

To eliminate one solution, anyway, I don't think you can override the native-type input functions because of ADL. You could implement `operator>>(istream, input_safe_int)` where `input_safe_int` is constructed from `int&`. Put a `try` block inside, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've had luck catching the [`std::ios_base::failure`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/failure) and then *re-raising* a [`std::system_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error) using [`errno`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errno):

```txt
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  broken/path: No such file or directory
```

```cpp
#include <fstream>

int main() {
  const std::string filename{ "broken/path" };
  try {
    std::ifstream file{ filename };
    file.exceptions(std::ios::failbit); // std::ios_base_failure is thrown here
  } catch (std::ios_base::failure&) {
    throw std::system_error{ errno, std::generic_category(), filename };
  }
}
```

This works on UNIX and Windows because "All `errno` values are … UNIX-compatible" ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/errno-doserrno-sys-errlist-and-sys-nerr?view=msvc-160)).