# ifstream how to determine why file does not open?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get std::fstream failure error messages and/or exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839644/get-stdfstream-failure-error-messages-and-or-exceptions)

I am using `ifstream` and I need to make opening of file very robust.

```
std::ifstream myfilestream(fileName);

if (!(myfilestream.is_open())){  // if not open how do I determine cause?

}
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/

Thanks

Comment: Just a side note, cplusplus.com is, although popular, not such a precise source of information.

Comment: For the reason **why** file does not open: [Getting meaningful error messages from fstream's in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2639324/237483)